# Enable DropDownList to return default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to return default value into my 2 dropdownlist. I have binded my DDLpolice with my SQLserver data while DDLocation is being added via the item properties. Whenever the admin selects a location, it will display the available choices.

Here are the 2 dropdownlist

1. lblocation
2. DDLpolice

I have these following values in the respective DDL

- lblocation

  1. Select Location ( Default Value )
  2. Select TownA ( Item value )
  3. Select TownB ( Item value )
- DDLpolice (Choice : TownA)

  1. Select Officer ( Default Value )
  2. Select 123 ( Item value )
  3. Select 124 ( Item value )
- DDpolice (Choice : TownB)

  1. Select Location ( Default Value )
  2. Select 126 ( Item value )
  3. Select 127 ( Item value )

In my database, respective Town has their respective policeIDs

- Town A

  1. 123
  2. 124
- Town B

  1. 126
  2. 127

Whenever the admin select a particular caseID, a location and a policeid, it automatically updates the database which is perfectly fine. Therefore, logically it should "refresh" the DDL and not display the selected policeID. However, the DDL's value still remain there.
I added a loadgrid so as to refresh my gridview information. I added an Item.Clear() on the DDL which entirely clears my DDL of my data.

```
public partial class AssignTask : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }

    }

    private void LoadGrid()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source =localhost;" +
            "Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI";
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT memberreportid, typeofcrime, location, crdatetime, citizenreport, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5 FROM MemberReport where handle='unhandled' AND caseprogress='inprogress'", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);

        GWCase.DataSource = ds;
        GWCase.DataBind();

        conn.Close();

    }

    protected void GWCase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblCID.Text = GWCase.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

    }

    protected void lblocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
        {
            connAdd.Open();


            var sql = "Select policeid from LoginRegisterPolice where location='" + lblocation.SelectedItem.Text + "' AND status='available' AND handle='offcase'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
            {
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                cmdAdd.Fill(ds2);

                DDLpolice.DataSource = ds2;
                DDLpolice.DataTextField = "policeid";
                DDLpolice.DataValueField = "policeid";
                DDLpolice.DataBind();
            }      
            connAdd.Close();
        }

    }

    protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (lblCID.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "Please select one case";
            return;
        }
        else if (lblocation.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Select Location"))
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "Please select a location";
            return;
        }
        else if (DDLpolice.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Select Officer"))
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "Please select an officer";
            return;

        }
        else
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "The case has been successfully assigned.";

        }



        using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
        {
            connAdd.Open();
            var sql = "Update AdminAssign Set assign ='" + DDLpolice.SelectedItem.Text + "' where memberreportid='" + lblCID.Text + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
            {
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            sql = "Insert into PoliceReport (memberreportid, policeid) values ('" + lblCID.Text.Trim() + "','" + DDLpolice.SelectedItem.Text + "')";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
            {
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            sql = "Update LoginRegisterPolice Set handle = '" + lblCID.Text + "' where policeid='" + DDLpolice.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
            {
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            sql = "Update MemberReport Set handle = 'handled' where memberreportid='" + lblCID.Text + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
            {
                cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connAdd.Close();
        }
        LoadGrid();


        lblCID.Text = "";
        lblocation.Items.Clear();
        DDLpolice.Items.Clear(); 
    }

    protected void DDLpolice_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Hence, I'm wondering how do i restore back my DDLocation, Default Values and Item values and DDLpolice default value.

Comment: You may also add the default value into your dropdownlist by using `Dropdown1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-------Select-------", ""));`,This will insert a default value into your `dropdownlist`,whenever you want to add a default value run that code on your control events.

Comment: There is one huge problem with .Insert(0,new ListItem).
Whenever i spam a particular button, it will consistently display the number of default value prior to the number of clicks i have spammed.

Comment: i have used the same method to insert `default` value but it just add `default` value once when you call it.

Comment: After clearing ddlLocation and ddlPolice dropdowns,bind the data for ddlLocation from DB and on the ddllocation_selectedchanged event,you have binded the data for ddlpolice.